# Mongodb how to get data not exist on other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have two collection `user` and `transaction`. I want get record where `user` not `exists` on collection `transaction`. Then i do that

```
[
    {
       "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "transaction",
            "localField":"_id",
            "foreignField":"user",
            "as" : "trans"
       }
   },
   {
       "$match": { "transaction.user": { "$exists": false } }
   },
   {"$limit":20}
]
```

but i dont got record what i want.

Comment: `$lookup` joins the data. The `_id` needs to be equal to the `user` field. Since there's always `_id` in MongoDB you will only get these `transactions` where there's a match. So do you want to get records with no **corresponding** transactions or just transactions without user field (just query that other collection in such case).

Comment: On which collection are you aggregating on? also you use `$lookup` as `"trans"`, but refer to doesn't refer to it in your `$match`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aggregate from `user` to `transaction` collection. And as mentioned by @thammada.ts, you should use `trans` in your `$match` like this

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "transaction",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user",
      "as": "trans"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "trans.user": {
        "$exists": false
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bogcK41an-B)

Also verify the type of both fields `_id` in `user` collection and `user`
in `transaction` collection.

Comment: Lets say that we need to compare two fields between `user` and `transaction` collections, then how can we achieve that with above aggregation query?